# "Listen" for change in full-screen status of a screen?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

Under X-11 there are various ways to detect if a screen is *currently* in full-screen mode.  Is there any way to "listen" for a change in full-screen status, other than checking every second what the current status is?  So far as I can tell (via `dbus-monitor`) nothing is sent to either the session nor system D-Bus when such a change in status happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean be "a screen in full-screen mode".

You can have a *window* in full screen mode. Size changes to windows (both requests and the actual change) are normal X events, and these are usually intercepted and dealt with by the Window Manager (WM).

So you can modify your WM's source code to pass these on to D-Bus, if that's what you want, but don't expect any one else to use this construction (X works perfectly fine without a D-Bus).

If you mean actual screen size changes, I'd assume these would be done through RANDR extension, so you need to intercept those.